# Finding IDs of duplicate records sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table which has lots of duplicate records namely tbl_voter with ID as primary key, auto increment. and there is another table tbl_notes which has notes for each voter. tbl_notes can have zero or more records of each voter. The ID from tbl_voter is the foreign key in the tbl_notes.

The problem is since there are duplicates in the voter table, there are duplicates in notes table as well.

For Example: tbl_voter

```
ID    Name    Address
01    abc     xyz
02    def     pqr
03    abc     xyz
04    abc     xyz
05    abc     xyz
06    def     pqr
```

tbl_notes

```
Noteid    ID     Note
A001      01     aaaaaa
A002      02     bbbbbb
A003      01     cccccc
A004      03     dddddd
A005      03     eeeeee
A006      04     ffffff
A007      05     gggggg
A008      01     hhhhhh
```

I want to find all the IDs of the original ones and their duplicates so as to update the tbl_notes

For Example: tbl_voter

```
ID    Name    Address
01    abc     xyz
02    def     pqr
```

tbl_notes

```
Noteid    ID     Note
A001      01     aaaaaa
A002      02     bbbbbb
A003      01     cccccc
A004      01     dddddd
A005      01     eeeeee
A006      01     ffffff
A007      01     gggggg
A008      01     hhhhhh
```

So far I have tried to find the duplicate records but it gives me the original ones as well as the duplicate ones. I need a query which returns me:

```
RealID     DuplicateID
01         03
01         04
01         05
02         06
```

The Query I tried :

```
select *
from tbl_voter a inner join 
(
select id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber,COUNT(*) AS dupes  from tbl_voter
where riding = '35019'
group by
firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber
having count(*) > 1 
) b on a.firstname = b.firstname
and a.lastname = b.lastname
and a.zip = b.zip
and a.firstname is not null
and b.firstname is not null
and a.riding='35019'
and a.housenumber=b.housenumber
order by a.firstname asc
```

If i add ID into the select query, it throws an error saying ID cannot be used in the group by query which is right as IDs will be different all the time.

The query with the IDs taken into consideration:

```
select a.id as realid, b.id as dupid, a.firstname,a.lastname,a.zip,a.housenumber
from tbl_voter a inner join 
(
select id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber,COUNT(*) AS dupes  from tbl_voter
where riding = '35019'
group by
id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber
having count(*) > 1 
) b on a.firstname = b.firstname
and a.lastname = b.lastname
and a.zip = b.zip
and a.firstname is not null
and b.firstname is not null
and a.riding='35019'
and a.housenumber=b.housenumber
order by a.firstname asc
```

If i get the IDs which are duplicates and the real ones, I can update the tbl_notes.

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: I cant remember the exact syntax but i think `GROUP_CONCAT` can be used to give all the ids where row,column= row,column id start by searching for that

Comment: @andrew The group_concat doesnt work for MSSQL. I tried looking for the alternatives, but it basically suggests to group the ID and not give the duplicate ones back. I need the duplicate ones so as to update them in both the tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am only going to focus on finding the table with the real id and the duplicated ids. At a basic level, what you are trying to to find all the id pairs where the information is duplicated. Essentially, we can start with this table:

> ```
> RealID     DuplicateID
> 01         01
> 01         03
> 01         04
> 01         05
> 03         01
> 03         03
> 03         04
> 03         05
> 04         01
> 04         03
> 04         04
> 04         05
> 05         01
> 05         03
> 05         04
> 05         05
> 02         02
> 02         06
> 06         02
> 06         06
> ```

Now, this is way more information than you want, but thinking about your table like this greatly simplifies the query. You want to create a self-join on the tbl_voter where all the non-id data is a match.

Next, let's filter out a lot of the information. Just by specifying that the realID must be smaller than the DuplicateID, you remove a lot of the unnecessary information. Then your table looks like this:

> ```
> RealID     DuplicateID
> 01         03
> 01         04
> 01         05
> 03         04
> 03         05
> 04         05
> 02         06
> ```

This is still excess information, but not as much. The last thing that you can do to eliminate the excess information is to group by the duplicateID and select the min(realID). This will give you the table you are looking for. That query looks like this:

```
Select min(v.id) as RealID, v2.id as DuplicateId
From tbl_voter v join tbl_voter v2
    on v.firstname = v2.firstname
    and v.lastname = v2.lastname
    and v.zip = v2.zip
    and v.firstname is not null
    and v2.firstname is not null
    and v.riding='35019'
    and v.riding = v2.riding
    and v.housenumber=v2.housenumber
    and v.id < v2.id
Group by v2.id
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I was trying to do this myself, I knew an inner join was gonna be needed somewhere

Comment: Well explained, Awesome answer! Worked as a charm! :) Thanks Jenn!

Comment: @Jenn Will this query consider null values as well? I mean if firstname and lastname are equal and the zip values are null, so will it match them or not? Can you help me frame a query which does the same? Thanks!

Comment: @Shashank If both of the zip values are null, then this query would work. However, I am assuming the duplicate entries would be because someone registered twice and maybe the second time they didn't include their zip. In this case it wouldn't match them, but you could do something like `and (v.zip = v1.zip or v.zip is null or v2.zip is null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try generating a ROW_NUMBER / RANK based on your key columns (not the auto-increment one)  and select all the records that have row_number =1. Something like the one below

SELECT id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber from
(SELECT id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber ORDER BY id,firstname,lastname,zip,housenumber) as rowNumber FROM tbl_voter) WHERE rowNumber=1

Comment: Doesn't work buddy, says an error near Where clause! :(

Comment: @Shashank Can you please let me know the Database and version?